# Rails 5 + font-awesome-rails gem - only boxes show

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, font-awesome

I've perused a number of similar issues & solutions, but still cannot get the boxes to show as font awesome icons on my rails 5 app ( upgraded from rails 4.2 )

in gemfile
`gem 'font-awesome-rails'`

in application.css.scss
`@import "font-awesome.css";`

As a test, I added `<i class="fab fa-adn"></i>` to my index.html.erb file, and this shows as a nice square []

This follows directions from 
https://github.com/bokmann/font-awesome-rails
&
http://fuzzyblog.io/blog/rails/2017/01/24/rails-tutorial-making-font-awesome-work-with-rails-5.html

No errors show on server readout, how can I solve this?

Comment: Shouldnt it be `<i class="fa fa-adn"></i>`

Comment: check the browser's console, sounds like the browser can't download the font file.

Comment: @HuzaifaSaifuddin that's it, thanks!

Comment: @GMarx You should have probably let me answer and given an approved answer.. Lol. Anyway happy to help. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved, there was a typo as pointed out in the comments above